# BottomNavigationView: set circle image and get view reference

Tags: android, android-menu

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I would like to put a custom image in place of the item.
I have tried several solutions to no avail.
The first problem is having the possibility to put a personalized menu.
To achieve this my menu has been constructed in the following way:

*profile_image_layout.xml* :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/windowBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="32dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="0dp">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

*bottom_navigation_menu_home.xml* :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
            android:id="@id/contacts"
            android:icon="@drawable/contacts"
            android:title="@string/contacts"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

        <item
            android:id="@id/calendar"
            android:icon="@drawable/calendar"
            android:title="@string/calendar"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

        <item
            android:id="@id/events"
            android:icon="@drawable/events"
            android:title="@string/events"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

        <item
            android:id="@id/groups"
            android:icon="@drawable/groups"
            android:title="@string/groups"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

        <item
            android:id="@id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/profile"
            android:title="@string/profile"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/profile_image_layout"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.FrameLayout"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    </menu>
```

After that, my goal was to put the image that interests me inside the "profile" item and in particular inside the profile_image_layout: "picture_profile" menu.
To recover the View I tried this way:

```
    FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) navigator.getMenu().findItem(R.id.profile).getActionView();
```

But from the rootView I can't access "picture_profile". Could anyone tell me if I'm doing well or what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use local Repository (SingleTon design pattern) that you keep the logged in profiles information in there and read the profile pic and information from that

for using Repository pattern you need to have a singleton class with required fields
i leave some links below for you

singleton design pattern: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton

here's a sample code from my old programmes (look at the repository pakage it's one of my first programmes and it's not very clean sorry for that):https://github.com/ErfanDP/TicTacToe_and_4_in_Row

Comment: OK but How can I retrieve a View as I wrote ? Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends where did you handle the menu and where it's placed(in fragment or activity)  you should use Callback on required place (i cant say it with this information)

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your menu.xml:

```
            <item
            android:id="@id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/profile"
            android:title="@string/profile"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/profile_image_layout"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.FrameLayout"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

1. android:actionLayout="@layout/profile_image_layout". should be app:actionLayout="@layout/profile_image_layout"。
2. You should use only one of ‘actionLayout’ & ’actionViewClass‘, or  'actionViewClass' will be chosen. After 'app:actionViewClass' deleted, it works.